# Efficientadapter OnItemClick listener

Tags: android, listview, adapter, clicklistener

I created custom `listView` using `Efficient adapter`. After i did this the `onItemclicklistener` of the list view is not working.
 whenever i click the `listView`, nothing will happen. I  dont know how to give `listener` to `efficient adapter`. I googled about this issue but i dint get any proper answer, if anyone having idea about this particular issue pls guide me.

Comment: can you please upload your code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this, in your onCreate() method

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen);

//Listener is added on the Aircraft List in order to handle touch events 

ListView List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

List.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

List.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

this is how you can add listener to ListView

If it is useful then please do not forget to mark this as an answer